# Populate Spinner with String[] data

Tags: android, json, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a JSON data from a server and i want to populate only the name columns into and Android Spinner. Unfortunately i get no error but the Spinner does not display the names i add to the adapter.
This is my JSON below:

```
{
"total": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "isDefault": false,
        "accountNumber": "000000000087",
        "accountName": null,
        "isVerified": true,
        "providerId": 2,
    }
],
"message": "Records Loaded",
"success": true
}
```

I only need to add the accountNumber to the Spinner, in the case where i have multiple data i should be able to add all the accountNumbers to the Spinner.

This is my code below:

```
try{
                    String[] names = new String[response.body().getData().length];
                    Data[] wallets = response.body().getData();
                    for (Data wallet : wallets) {
                        addToWallets(wallet);
                    }
                    int i = 0;
                    for(Data o : response.body().getData()){
                        names[i] = o.getAccountNumber();
                        i++;
                    }
                    Log.i("loadAllWalletsAPI", "all wallets API working successfully");
                    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                            (getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                    names); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                            .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the default color of text in spinner is white, so You cannot see it. Try replacing android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item with Your own xml and add android:textColor="@color/black" to the text view in it.

this is a simple example of simple_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000"
    />
```